# ALS methods - train, trainImplicit and fit

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, apache-spark-ml

What is the difference between Difference between als.train(, als.fit() , als.traimImplicit()

Answer (score 2):

First of all we should know difference between implicit and explicit feedback.

explicit preference (also referred as "explicit feedback"), such as "rating" given to item by users.

implicit preference (also referred as "implicit feedback"), such as "view" and "buy" history.

For better understanding you can look at below two links:

[Why does ALS.trainImplicit give better predictions for explicit ratings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007724/why-does-als-trainimplicit-give-better-predictions-for-explicit-ratings)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133565/how-to-set-preferences-for-als-implicit-feedback-in-collaborative-filtering

train and trainimplicit are used in mllib package which is used for rdd data. With spark dataframe, spark has new module with name ml. In ml package it uses spark dataframe for calculating ratings and the method name is fit. fit method from ml use matrix factorization. for more detail check doc for ALS(ml) class.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/926e3a1efe9e142804fcbf52146b22700640ae1b/python/pyspark/ml/recommendation.py

Also,ml module is faster than mllib.

[What's the difference between Spark ML and MLLIB packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835829/whats-the-difference-between-spark-ml-and-mllib-packages)